# Finding volume inside a paraboloid and inside a sphere

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

I want to find the volume inside the paraboloid $z= x^2 +y^2$ and inside the sphere $x^2 +y^2 +z^2 =12$.

So, I wrote $x=r\cos t, y=r \sin t$, find out  $0\le r \le \sqrt 3$ and $0 \le  2 \pi$. We also have $z = r^2 $ the paraboloid and $z = \sqrt{12-r^2}$. Now, why is the desired volume is given as:

$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt 3}( \sqrt{12-r^2} -r^2)r\,\,drdt?$$

Why do we subtract two $z$ values in this way and not use just one of them? Thanks.

Comment: Consider that the volume calculation starts as a triple integration of 1. The upper bound of $z$ is $\sqrt{12-r^2}$ and the lower bound is $r^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region is bounded above by $z_1=\sqrt{12-r^2}$ and bounded below by $z_2 = r^2$. That is why we subtract them.

For example, you might want to consider a simpler problem. Suppose you want to compute the area between $y=x^2$ and $y=x$ where $x$ is in between $0$ and $1$. We would evaluate this as $\int_0^1 (x-x^2) \, dx$.

Comment: Do not we have something like a sliced cone which has a top that looks like the surface of a sphere?

Comment: and what about the bottom?

Comment: Oh, I see. So, does  "inside the paraboloid and inside the sphere" means that we seek for the region between them?

Comment: yes, the region between them.

Comment: the bottom is the bottom of the paraboloid.

Comment: Yup, which is why we subtract them.